# Flask - Setting root directory

Tags: python, flask

I have a folder structure that looks like so:

```
myproject/
    - flask_app/
        - app.py
        - templates/
    - module1.py
    - module2/
        - db.py
        - models/
```

I'm running into ImportErrors in my Flask application when trying to do the following:

```
from module2 import db
# or something else like
import module1

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is obviously because the Flask app is running from its own subdirectory "flask_app". I normally would try and get around this by running it like so:

```
python -m flask_app.app
```

But this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Is there a way I run my flask app from the root folder without resorting to relative imports (using older version of Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `python -m flask_app.app`, most likely `sys.path` won't include the `myproject` path.

Easiest would be to put a top-level script in the `myproject` directory; lets call it `runsite.py`:

```
from flask_app.app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

and run that with Python:

```
$ python runsite.py
```